# Prove that if $f : F^4 → F^2$ is linear and $\ker f =\{ (x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)^T: x_1 = 3x_2,\ x_3 = 7x_4\}$ then $f$ is surjective

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, vector-spaces

> Prove that if $f : F^4 → F^2$ is a linear map such that $$\ker (f)=
> \big\{ (x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)^T\ :\ x_1 = 3x_2,\ x_3 = 7x_4\big\}$$ then $f$ is surjective.

I know that all $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ that satisfy the above properties are in the kernel, so I am assuming they are mapped to $(0,0)^T$. However, how do I show that all other elements of $F^2$ are getting mapped onto? That is for an arbitary pair $y_1,y_2 \in F^2$ how do I know that there exist $f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)^T=(y_1,y_2)^T$ and not a single element is missed?

Comment: You might consider to show that the kernel has dimension $2$ and some theoretical results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
If $f\colon U \to V$ is linear and $U,V$ are finite dimensional vector spaces, then
[$$\dim(U)=\dim(\operatorname{Im}(f))+\dim(\ker(f))$$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem)

> Show that $\dim(\ker(f))=2$. Then we have $\dim(\operatorname{Im}(f))=2$ and conclude using $\operatorname{Im}(f)\subset F^2$.

Comment: So using the Rank Nullity I can show that $im(f)=2$, but I'm not able to see why this would imply surjectivity. Certanly I see that $2<4=dim U$

Comment: @Epsilon $f$ is surjective if $\operatorname{Im}(f)=V=F^2$

Comment: thanks, I didn't know this fact

Comment: @Epsilon I recommend you to recall the definition of [$\operatorname{Im}(f)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)) to understand why it is true.

Comment: So since the image has dim $2$, it means that there are $2$ elements from $F^4$ mapping to it at all times. Thus every $x,y$ is mapped on by some elements in $F^4$?

Comment: @Epsilon Note that $\operatorname{Im}(f)=\{y\in F^2\mid \exists x\text{ with }f(x)=y\}$ and $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ is a subspace of dimension $2$ in the $2$-dimensional vector space $F^2$.